# callback function called before executing it in the second page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have in my main page a `Container` which use as child a widget `PageView` with a callback function `onBookPlace`.

```
Container(
  child: PageView(
  onBookPlace: onBookPlace(
   dateStart, dateEnd
  ),
  ),
 )
```

In my `PageView`, I have the function `onBookPlace` which should be called when I press `onTap`

```
class PageView extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback onBookPlace;

  const PageView({Key key,this.onBookPlace})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return GestureDetector(
     onTap:() {onBookPlace()},
                                 
   );}}
```

But the problem here is my function is called before I click over the `GestureDetector` widget. It's called on the construction of the `PageView`.

How to fix this? I mean that the callback should only be called when I click over the `GestureDetector` widget.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should pass a reference to your function, instead of calling it right away. So you probably should remove `()`

```
Container(
  child: PageView1(onBookPlace: onBookPlace)
)
```

**EDIT:**
if you want to pass some parameters with your function then you can create another function to pass as your callback.
For example you can use anonymous function.

```
Container(
   child: PageView1(onBookPlace: () => onBookPlace(dateStart, dateEnd))
)
```

The basic idea is that when you want to pass a callback function you want to pass the function itself, not its result.
By putting parentheses there you call the function and pass its result, instead of passing a reference to your handler function.

Comment: I edited my question, the function is with parameters onBookPlace(
   dateStart, dateEnd
  ).